# How do I add a startup script to an existing VM from the developer console?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an existing, already configured VM on Google Cloud Platform. It was created without a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript), but I'd like to add one now.

How do I add it from the console.developers.google.com web interface?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can add a startup script to an already created VM by creating a new custom metadata field. Follow these steps:

1. Get to your VM's configuration page: Navigate to https://console.developers.google.com  Click your project. Go to Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances. Click the name of your VM.
2. Scroll down to Custom Metadata. Click Edit.
3. Create a new metadata field. Set the key to `startup-script`.
4. Paste your startup script into the value field. Don't forget the shebang. Here's an example of a valid script.

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   apt-get update
   apt-get install -y apache2
   cat <<EOF > /var/www/index.html
   <html><body><h1>Hello World</h1>
   <p>This page was created from a simple startup script!</p>
   </body></html>
   EOF
   ```
5. Restart your VM. Enjoy the yields of your awesome startup script.

Comment: Link to official docs from Google for exactly this issue: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances

Comment: Not working for Ubuntu 16.04 due to a bug? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904904

Comment: awesome , Thank working, but not with direct script, but with the script path, if you can test and confirm it will be perfect, but working.

Comment: @PascalGula The above solution is working for Ubuntu 16.04 in GCP.

Comment: For those with an aversion to the ambiguity inherent in directions which include an attempt to describe navigating through a UI, you can use `gcloud compute instances add-metadata`

Comment: are they supposed to be provided in quotes?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to mimming's answer, I was looking for this to solve my issue regarding multiple IP, and his answer help me get started and finally solved my problem by add below startup-script when reboot the instance.

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 60
/usr/sbin/ip route add default via 10.8.8.1 dev eth1 table rt1
/usr/sbin/ip rule add from 10.8.8.3/32 table rt1
/usr/sbin/ip rule add to 10.8.8.3/32 table rt1
```

remember to add "sleep 60" otherwise it might not working cause the networking not started yet.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct as per the question.

But what I was looking for to add multiple .sh scripts in startup metadata of GCP VM via gcloud command.

Below works for me (maybe it will help someone)

```
To add multiple key-value pairs at once, separate them with commas:

$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata test-instance \
      --metadata=important-data="2 plus 2 equals\
   4",unimportant-data=zero
```

Docs link- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-metadata